# bug? in codesign --remove-signature feature

Tags: macos, digital-signature

I would like to remove the digital signature from a Mac app that has been signed with codesign. There is an undocumented option to codesign, --remove-signature, which by it's name seems to be what I need. However, I can't get it to work. I realize it is undocumented, but I could really use the functionality. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
 codesign -s MyIdentity foo.app
```

works normally, signing the app

```
 codesign --remove-signature foo.app
```

does disk activity for several seconds, then says

```
 foo.app: invalid format for signature
```

and foo.app has grown to 1.9 GB!!! (Specifically, it is the executable in foo.app/Contents/Resources/MacOS that grows, from 1.1 MB to 1.9 GB.)

The same thing happens when I try to sign/unsign a binary support tool instead of a .app.

Any ideas?

---

Background: This is my own app; I'm not trying to defeat copy protection or anything like that.

I would like to distribute a signed app so that each update to the app won't need user approval to read/write the app's entries in the Keychain. However, some people need to modify the app by adding their own folder to /Resources. If they do that, the signature becomes invalid, and the app can't use it's own Keychain entries.

The app can easily detect if this situation has happened. If the app could then remove it's signature, everything would be fine. Those people who make this modification would need to give the modified, now-unsigned app permission to use the Keychain, but that's fine with me.

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, but I've updated a public-domain tool called `unsign` which modifies executables to clear out signatures.

https://github.com/steakknife/unsign

Comment: Promoting code you've authored (even partially) is fine, so long as you clearly detail how the OP can use it to do what they are trying to do. Otherwise, it is considered to be spam.

Comment: Yeah, this really has nothing to do with the OP's question, which has to do with removing signatures and resigning **a bundle**, not just a single executable or binary file.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue today. I can confirm that the `--remove-signature` option to Apple's `codesign` is (and remains, six years after the OP asked this question) *seriously* buggy.

For a little background, Xcode (and Apple's command line developer tools) include the `codesign` utility, but there is not included a tool for removing signatures. However, as this is something that needs to be done in certain situations pretty frequently, there is included a *completely undocumented* option:

`codesign --remove-signature` which (one assumes, given lack of documentation) should, well, be fairly self-explanatory but unfortunately, it *rarely* works as intended without some effort. So I ended up writing a script that should take care of the OP's problem, mine, and similar. If enough people find it here and find it useful, let me know and I'll put it on GitHub or something.

---

```
#!/bin/sh # codesign_remove_for_real -- working `codesign --remove-signature`
# (c) 2018 G. Nixon. BSD 2-clause minus retain/reproduce license requirements.

total_size(){
  # Why its so damn hard to get decent recursive filesize total in the shell?
  # - Darwin `du` doesn't do *bytes* (or anything less than 512B blocks)
  # - `find` size options are completely non-standardized and doesn't recurse
  # - `stat` is not in POSIX at all, and its options are all over the map...
  # - ... etc. 
  # So: here we just use `find` for a recursive list of *files*, then wc -c
  # and total it all up. Which sucks, because we have to read in every bit
  # of every file. But its the only truly portable solution I think.
  find "$@" -type f -print0 | xargs -0n1 cat | wc -c | tr -d '[:space:]'
}

# Get an accurate byte count before we touch anything. Zero would be bad.
size_total=$(total_size "$@") && [ $size_total -gt 0 ] || exit 1

recursively_repeat_remove_signature(){
  # `codesign --remove-signature` randomly fails in a few ways.
  # If you're lucky, you'll get an error like:
  # [...]/codesign_allocate: can't write output file: [...] (Invalid argument)
  # [...] the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
  # or something to that effect, in which case it will return non-zero.
  # So we'll try it (suppressing stderr), and if it fails we'll just try again.
  codesign --remove-signature --deep "$@" 2>/dev/null ||
    recursively_repeat_remove_signature "$@"

  # Unfortunately, the other very common way it fails is to do something? that
  # hugely increases the binary size(s) by a seemingly arbitrary amount and
  # then exits 0. `codesign -v` will tell you that there's no signature, but
  # there are other telltale signs its not completely removed. For example,
  # if you try stripping an executable after this, you'll get something like
  # strip: changes being made to the file will invalidate the code signature
  # So, the solution  (well, my solution) is to do a file size check; once
  # we're finally getting the same result, we've probably been sucessful.
  # We could of course also use checksums, but its much faster this way.
  [ $size_total == $(total_size "$@") ] ||
    recursively_repeat_remove_signature "$@"

  # Finally, remove any leftover _CodeSignature directories.
  find "$@" -type d -name _CodeSignature -print0 | xargs -0n1 rm -rf
} 

signature_info(){
  # Get some info on code signatures. Not really required for anything here.
  for info in "-dr-" "-vv"; do codesign $info "$@";  done # "-dvvvv" 
}

# If we want to be be "verbose", check signature before. Un/comment out:
# echo >&2; echo "Current Signature State:" >&2; echo >&2; signature_info "$@"


# So we first remove any extended attributes and/or ACLs (which are common,
# and tend to interfere with the process here) then run our repeat scheme.
xattr -rc "$@" && chmod -RN "$@" && recursively_repeat_remove_signature "$@"

# Done!


# That's it; at this point, the executable or bundle(s) should sucessfully
# have truly become stripped of any code-signing. To test, one could
# try re-signing it again with an ad-hoc signature, then removing it again:
# (un/comment out below, as you see fit)

# echo >&2 && echo "Testing..." >&2; codesign -vvvvs - "$@" &&
  # signature_info "$@" && recursively_repeat_remove_signature "$@"

# And of course, while it sometimes returns false positives, lets at least:
codesign -dvvvv "$@" || echo "Signature successfully removed!" >&2 && exit 0
```

Comment: I was trying your script today (macOS 10.15.7) and got this error: `./codesign_remove_for_real.sh: line 38: [: 503504: unary operator expected`. Do you have a fix for this? It also seems to work just fine, second time I run it on the same file it now says no signature found.

Comment: Also tried this script (as a last resort to try and fix GitKraken on 12.0 beta 8):
`[1]    51813 segmentation fault  codesign_remove_for_real.sh`

Comment: ./codesign_remove_for_real.sh: line 38: [: 33425: unary operator expected
./codesign_remove_for_real.sh: line 38: [: 33425: unary operator expected
./codesign_remove_for_real.sh: line 38: [: 33425: unary operator expected
zsh: segmentation fault  ./codesign_remove_for_real.sh test

Answer (score 4):

[Here's the source](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-36515/src/codesign.cpp) for `codesign` which lists all options, including those not covered by the command-line `-h` and man page.

Also, [here is Apple's tech note on recent changes in how code-signing works](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there's something strange going on when you did `--remove-signature`.

However, instead of trying to un-code-sign, you should change the way your user put extra files in the `Resources`. Instead, designate a certain path, usually

```
~/Library/Application Support/Name_Of_Your_App/
```

or maybe

```
~/Library/Application Support/Name_Of_Your_App/Resources/
```

and ask the user to put extra files there. Then, in your code, always check for the directory in addition to the files in the `Resources` when you need to read a file.

Comment: The the user may have several copies of the app with different extra files, and may move the application around. If their extra files are in the app, it all works. Otherwise, I have to somehow keep track of the different files based on the location of the app, and then if the app moves it stops working. Altogether a mess.

Answer (score 1):

On a second reading of this question, another thought: perhaps a better approach to accomplish what the ultimate goal of the question is would be not to *remove* the signatures, but to have users (via a script/transparently) **re**-sign the app after modification, using an ad-hoc signature. That is, `codesign -fs - [app]`, I believe. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105588/anyone-with-experience-in-hacking-the-codesigning-on-os-x