# How to undo codesign?

Tags: macos, codesign

In an attempt to codesign gdb, I used an incorrect certificate, so now gdb is codesigned but does not work as expected.

I attempted to codesign gdb using the correct certificate, however codesign complains that gdb is already signed.

So how to undo it?

The codesign command I used was:

```
codesign -s gdb-cert gdb
```

Comment: answered here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26320600/2975337

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not well documented at all, from what I can tell, but you *may be* able to remove code signing via:

```
codesign --remove-signature gdb
```

Comment: This removes a signature, but note that it leaves the binary unable to be re-signed with the `codesign` tool afterwards. You should just `brew reinstall gdb` and call it a day.

Comment: Yup, but see my answer at the the linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500381/bug-in-codesign-remove-signature-feature?noredirect=1&lq=1

And there is definitely more to it than `brew reinstall gdb`; one has to have the right certificate in your Keychain, like with lldb: https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/docs/code-signing.txt

Answer (score 7):

Add `--force` to the arguments of your `codesign` command to make it re-sign something.

For example:

```
codesign --force --sign gdb-cert gdb
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with removing signature as suggested by Micheal:

```
unsupported type or version of signature
```

Finally I used -f flag and  force loaded new certificate.