# macOS Mojave: How to achieve codesign to enable debugging (gdb)?

Tags: debugging, gdb, geany, macos-mojave

There are many topics floating around covering codesign issues with macOS, from 10.5 onward.
What I wanted to achieve is, to get Geany working with the GNU Debugger (gdb). Debugger is found in geany, but the (already quite known) error message is:

```
Error message from debugger back end:
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 39847: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 39847: (os/kern) failure (0x5).\n (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Generally there are many restrictions to consider that (should) allow the usage of gdb, e.g. gdb 8.0.1 may work, gdb 8.1 will not work at all - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49104154/7060954), also confirmed in Lazarus Wiki.

0) I created my certificate "gdb-cert" according to the steps covered by various instructions. Example [here](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/mac-os-codesign-tool.htm)

1) I followed the steps of codesigning the gdb executable file (source: [gdb](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gnat_ugn_unw/Codesigning-the-Debugger.html), and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678528/7060954)) which is in my case under

> /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.0.1/bin/gdb

(note again, there are issues with 8.1 for some languages - pascal too). If you want to make sure that code is signed, go for

```
$ codesign -vvvv  gdb
```

in the respective directory. Mine is.

2) Make sure that the certificate was actually assigned to be eligible for code signing - it is in my case. It is also trusted - which is necessary.

3) I also tried the other way to get gdb running described above, where the file was edited (please note, that SIP has to be disabled in recovery first!!!!)
**Modifications only work if `csrutil disable` is used in the recovery.**

```
sudo nano /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
```

Devastating thing, after this step, **no code editor would start up again (!!), until this change is undone** (Geany, Atom, Text Editor, MS Visual Studio - all broken after inserting -sp to the file)

4) In some topics I found that debugging will only work if the command `csrutil enable --withouth` debug is used in the recovery. This hasn't changed anything.

**Eventually I ended up having:**

a certificate to code sign

a gdb exectuable file which is signed according to my statement above

a com.apple.taskgated.plist file not having populated the string -sp attribute

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could confirm this behavior, a solution to this even more :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is related to codesign entitlements. you must add "com.apple.security.cs.debugger" key in signing process.

for example you must change `codesign -fs gdbcert /usr/local/bin/gdb` to `codesign --entitlements gdb.xml -fs gdbcert /usr/local/bin/gdb` .

gdb.xml content must something like following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Working well !! Your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: Works for me even after all the instructions here failed: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

Comment: @JoshHaberman FYI I updated https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin with the instructions herein.

Comment: Note to others using this answer, you have to create a certificate named gdbcert in keychain assistant

Comment: @DomQ the signing step with the entitlements doesn't work because it tries to find the cert by identity -- which is usually email address, *not* the cert common name. I got around it by putting "gdb-cert" for both common name and email in the cert when I created it. Then I could run `codesign --entitlements gdb-entitlement.xml -fs gdb-cert $(which gdb)`

Answer (score 4):

The `log` command is helpful for troubleshooting code signing issues. Here is what I used (on Mojave):

`log stream --predicate 'process == "taskgated" OR (process == "kernel" AND eventMessage CONTAINS "macOSTaskPolicy")' --info`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't modify `com.apple.taskgated.plist` so no issues with any of the text editors you listed.  The fix I'm using though, unfortunately does require me to run `gdb` with `sudo` (which I didn't need for the fix I had on High Sierra).  Not using Geany, but these are the slightly modified steps I used for `gdb` on Mac Mojave (with thanks to the original author who published instructions for High Sierra):

1. Run `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/9ec9fb27a33698fc7636afce5c1c16787e9ce3f3/Formula/gdb.rb`.
2. Follow with  `brew pin gdb`
3. Open *Keychain Access*
4. In menu, open *Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate*
5. Give it a name (e.g. `gdbcert`)
6. Identity type: *Self Signed Root*
7. Certificate type: *Code Signing*
8. Check: *Let Me Override Defaults*
9. Continue with default options until *Specify a Location For*
10. Set Keychain location to System. If this yields the following error: `Certificate Error: Unknown Error =-2,147,414,007` Set Location to Login, Unlock System by click on the lock at the top left corner and drag and drop the certificate `gdbcert` to the *System Keychain*.
11. Find the certificate in *System keychain*.
12. Double click certificate.
13. Expand *Trust*, set *Code signing* to *Always Trust*
14. Restart taskgated in terminal: `sudo killall taskgated`  or possibly  `ps aux | grep taskgated` then  `kill -9 <pid>`
15. Enable root account by following the steps given below:
16. Open *System Preferences*
17. Go to *User & Groups > Unlock*
18. Login *Options > Join* (next to Network Account Server)
19. Click *Open Directory Utility*
20. Go up to *Edit > Enable Root User*
21. Codesign gdb using your certificate: `codesign -fs gdbcert /usr/local/bin/gdb`  I ended up using  `sudo killall taskgated && codesign -fs gdbcert /usr/local/bin/gdb`
22. Codesign authenticate as root user
23. Shut down your mac and restart in recovery mode (hold down command-R until Apple logo appears)
24. Open terminal window
25. Modify System Integrity Protection to allow debugging: `csrutil enable --without debug`
26. Reboot your Mac. Debugging with `gdb` should now work as expected.
27. Run `gdb` with `sudo`; for example `sudo gdb -q ./a.out`

Comment: didn't work for me: it's hitting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529838/gdb-8-2-cant-recognized-executable-file-on-macos-mojave-10-14