# gdb run command fails on mac Mojave

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, gdb

I am using mac Mojave 10.14.5.

Previously I had [codesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699661/macos-mojave-how-to-achieve-codesign-to-enable-debugging-gdb) issue, and resolved from [link](https://timnash.co.uk/getting-gdb-to-semi-reliably-work-on-mojave-macos/).

After resolving codesign issue, when I run gdb, the program just stops like below.

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from CIRMERGE...
Reading symbols from /Users/___/Project/CIRMERGE.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/CIRMERGE...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/___/Project/CIRMERGE 
[New Thread 0x1703 of process 601]
[New Thread 0x1903 of process 601]
```

First, I followed the same instruction given in the above link, removing 
`set startup-with-shell enable from` ~/.gdbinit. (It was empty and I tried disable option too)

Secondly, I found someone having [similar problem](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/34750) with me, so tried to reinstall gdb head, but installing gdb with --HEAD fails like below

```
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/sean/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gdb/02.make:
darwin-nat-info.c:620:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'target_gdbarch'
  if (gdbarch_addr_bit (target_gdbarch ()) <= 32)
                        ^
darwin-nat-info.c:657:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'target_gdbarch'
        uiout->field_core_addr ("start", target_gdbarch (), r_start);
                                         ^
  CXX    disasm.o
darwin-nat-info.c:658:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'target_gdbarch'
        uiout->field_core_addr ("end", target_gdbarch (), r_start + r_size);
```

Here is my gdb configuration.

```
This GDB was configured as follows:
   configure --host=x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0 --target=x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
             --with-auto-load-dir=:${prefix}/share/auto-load
             --with-auto-load-safe-path=:${prefix}/share/auto-load
             --with-expat
             --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.3/share/gdb (relocatable)
             --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.3/lib/gdb (relocatable)
             --without-libunwind-ia64
             --without-lzma
             --without-babeltrace
             --without-intel-pt
             --disable-libmcheck
             --without-mpfr
             --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
             --without-guile
             --disable-source-highlight
             --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.3/lib/debug (relocatable)
```

I am trying to debug my cpp code for hours, so any help would be appreciated.