# GDB Compatibility Issue on OSX Mojave

Tags: macos, gdb, macos-mojave

I was using gdb before Mojave update but now it is throwing errors:

`(gdb) file a.out
BFD: /Users/aliomerkeser/Desktop/a.out: unknown load command 0x32
BFD: /Users/aliomerkeser/Desktop/a.out: unknown load command 0x32
"/Users/aliomerkeser/Desktop/a.out": not in executable format: File format not recognized`

Is that a compatibility issue or a configuration issue of mine?

I tried downgrading gdb and re-codesigning gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known bug with gdb on Mojave. Still not resolved. In the thread below there is a solution proposed which involves rebuilding gdb with some changes.

[gdb 8.2 can't recognized executable file on macOS Mojave 10.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529838/gdb-8-2-cant-recognized-executable-file-on-macos-mojave-10-14)

Update:
8.2 has officially incorporated these changes, so doesnt have to be done manually.

Comment: While it's fine to link to an answer, your answer should be useful even if the link doesn't work. Maybe quote the relevant parts of the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind still doesn't work on OSX Mojave but I am using heapusage an it is a pretty good alternative to valgrind

[heapusage](https://github.com/d99kris/heapusage)