# Unable to to debug the binary after build from cmake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, gdb

I'm using cmake to build the debug version via `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`

I got **CMakeCache.txt, CMakeFiles, Makefile, cmake_install.cmake** files/folders and the compiled binary, say **test**, in the build folder.

when I start the gdb by `gdb ./test` I got the following out put

> GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1 Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
>
> Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for
>   details. This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0". Type
>   "show configuration" for configuration details.
>
> For bug reporting instructions, please see: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/.
>
> Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/.
>
> For help, type "help".
>
> Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
>
> BFD: /Users/sln/Project/repos/C++/Primer/debug/test: unknown
>   load command 0x32
>
> BFD: /Users/sln/Project/repos/C++/Primer/debug/test:
>   unknown load command 0x32
>
> "/Users/sln/Project/repos/C++/Primer/debug/./test": not in executable
>   format: File format not recognized

And I add the break point to main function by `(gdb) break main` and the following message was print out

> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
>
> Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])

By input `y` to the upper question I got

> Breakpoint 1 (main) pending.

Then `(gdb) run` command gives the error

> Starting program:
>
> No executable file specified.
>
> Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.

And finally `(gdb) file` leads to

> No executable file now.
>
> No symbol file now.

**Question:** I wonder which part was wrong?

Here is my CmakeList.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

add_executable( test
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test_nav.h
)
```

Comment: Try `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..` (add space after `-D`).

Comment: @ks1322 Not working for me

Comment: Try cmake CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..

Comment: Can you edit your question to show all the output of your gdb session between `gdb ./test` and `"No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command."`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Updated

Comment: Oh. You're on a Mac. Maybe the answers in [gdb 8.2 can't recognized executable file on macOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52529838/gdb-8-2-cant-recognized-executable-file-on-macos-mojave-10-14) will help.